# Facing error running pod install Flutter ios after changing ios platform specification in podfile

Tags: flutter, cocoapods, pod-install

I am facing issues with running pod install. Before I tried to uncomment platform specification in podfiles for ios (set to 4.0) as it was required, while I was running main.dart. Could anyone please help me to solve it?

Full error message:

```
Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_c_0_4.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/0/4/Flutter/3.0.0/Flutter.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.10.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "games_services":
  In Podfile:
    games_services (from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/games_services/macos`)
Specs satisfying the `games_services (from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/games_services/macos`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:317:in `raise_error_unless_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:299:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `tap'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `unwind_for_conflict'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:682:in `attempt_to_activate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1082:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1080:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:125:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:422:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:244:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
Exception: Error running pod install
Exited
```

Comment: Try to open xcode Runner -> General -> Deployment target. And change the deployment version for all the platform your are targeting until this error message doesn't display